# Estimate upper human body (hands, shoulder) size

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to estimate the size of the human body by using a webcam. I want to estimate the upper-body measurements like arms, shoulder etc.

How do I proceed?

Comment: This may help a little... https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053949/2836621

Comment: do you have information on how far the person is from the camera ?

You might need that information, since the image size alone might not suffice

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it